# Update table value from a second table by joining a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I have 3 tables, TableA, TableB and TableC

I want to migrate the data from TableA column DateA to TableB column DateB, only if the date field is null in table B (I don’t want to overwrite any existing data)

I need to join TableA and TableB using TableC to match the A and B rows that should be updated by their RobotNumber.

TableA

```
RobotNumber         DateA
11                  12/12/2015
12                  01/05/2018
13                  05/03/2019
```

TableB

```
RobotID       Date
2             null
3             07/01/2018
4             null
```

TableC

```
RobotNumber RobotID      
11          2
12          3
13          4
```

I have tried to join the tables and do the update like so but the query times out:

```
UPDATE TableB 
SET TableB.DateB = TableA.DateA
FROM TableB 
inner join TableC c on TableB.RobotID = c.RobotID
inner join TableA a on a.RobotNumber = c.RobotNumber
where TableB.RobotID not in (select RobotID from TableB where DateB is not null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by getting rid of the `NOT IN`:

```
UPDATE TableB 
    SET TableB.DateB = TableA.DateA
    FROM TableB JOIN
         TableC c 
         ON TableB.RobotID = c.RobotID JOIN
         TableA a 
         ON a.RobotNumber = c.RobotNumber
    WHERE TableB.DateB is null;
```

Then, you should also have indexes on `TableC(RobotID)` and `TableA(RobotNumber, DateA)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but shouldnt the last line be WHERE TableB.DateB is null;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have indexes on the columns used in the `JOIN` clause.

In other words, you should have indexes at least on the `RobotID` column in `TableB` and `TableC` and on the `RobotNumber` column in `TableA` and `TableC`.

Also, if `RobotID` is the primary key in the `TableB`, you could change the `WHERE` condition in the last line to: `WHERE TableB.DateB IS NOT NULL`